# XML para C en Netbeans

Tags: c, netbeans

Estoy usando Fedora 26 y Netbeans 8.2
Necesito incluir la librería libxml para parsear archivos XML con el lenguaje C.
No encuentro información de como hacer esto.
Ya tengo las librerías libxml y libxml2 instaladas en Fedora.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: no encuentras informacion sobre que cosa?

Comment: Mira este link a ver si te viene bien la informacion: https://totaki.com/poesiabinaria/2012/06/leer-un-archivo-xml-en-c-con-libxml2-con-todos-los-nombres-atributos-y-contenidos/